# Stop all CompletableFutures once custom Runtime exception is throw in any of the threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I have a Spring Boot service which is supposed to do independent calculations (taxes and invoices). Requirement is to stop all running threads if any of the threads throws RuntimeException.

So now I have a service:

```
    @Service
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class MyFutureService implements FutureService {
    
        private final Executor executor;
        
        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Boolean> callculateInvoices(Object params) {
              return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                boolean isOk = true;
                sleep(5000);
                Object intermediateResult = getInfoData(params);
                if (intermediateResult == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("invoices error");
                }
                isOk = useIntermediateResult(intermediateResult, params);
                return isoK;
            }, executor);
        }
    
        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Boolean> callculateTaxes(Object params) {
          return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                boolean isOk = true;
                sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("This shouldn't be printed!!"); //This actually does get printed.
                return isoK;
            }, executor);
        }
   }

   private void sleep(long sleep){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Object getInfoData(Object params){
        return null;
    }
    
    private boolean useIntermediateResult(Object x, Object y){
            return new Random().nextBoolean();
        }
    }
```

In main service code:

```
@GetMapping("/Bundle4")
public Object test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   CompletableFuture<Boolean> invoicesFuture =
            extensionValidatorService.callculateInvoices(someParams);


    CompletableFuture<Boolean> taxesFuture =
            extensionValidatorService.callculateTaxes(someParams);

    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFutures =
            CompletableFuture.allOf(invoicesFuture, taxesFuture);

    combinedFutures.get();
    

    if (invoicesFuture .get() && taxesFuture.get()){
      //saveToDb(someParams);
    }
    return "Saved to DB";
}
```

After line `combindeFutures.get()`, I need some kind of "listener" or something which will be able to get to the first RuntimeException that was throw (and rethrow it so the **ControllerAdvice** can pick it up) in any of the threads and STOP all others which are not done.

Comment: Stopping threads in Java is kind of complicated if I recall correctly, for example look  [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop). I would create a shared object containing a single boolean flag (```exceptionOccurred = false```)  and pass this object to all long-running calculation methods as a parameter. As long as you are about to throw the exception, set the flag to ```true```. All other threads will see the change immediately. In your calculation loops poll the flag on each iteration and break the loop if the flag is true. In this way you are not dependent on the framework.

Comment: I think what you want is task cancellation, not "stoppping threads", but CompletableFuture has its own policies regarding cancellation that makes it ill suited for this. It depends on what really you will be doing in the calculation tasks, if they can be interrupted, I think it's cleaner to use a normal Future returned by the submit method of an ExecutorService.

Comment: If the calculation tasks cannot be interrupted (i.e. they are completely CPU bound) there's no way around it to make them cooperate by sharing state (the flag mentioned by @roccobaroccoSC). Just make sure to use a volatile boolean or an AtomicBoolean or better an AtomicReference (in which you can put the Exception of the first throwing task... so that you will know later who threw first).

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC That shared flag would need to be [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), not `boolean`/`Boolean`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. I believe the posted link explains exactly how to do it.

Comment: @BasilBourque: However, I believe in OP's case having an atomic boolean is not necessary because the value is supposed to be changed only once in one direction. Even if a second thread overwrites the value, it does not matter. Also, skipping one or two iterations before ending the loops is seemingly a non-issue. I would use simple booleans unless there is a good reason to require atomic operation on the flag. Please do let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC If you don't mark the boolean with "volatile", the compiler might optimize it out.

Comment: Good point! Thanks.